# Check multiple decorators before accessing a view in django

Tags: django

Im using **@user_passes_test** decorator to check whether the user has permissions to the view. Each usertype is given a function that is used with the decorator. Like this

```
@user_passes_test(ismanager,login_url='userauth:forbiddnpage')
@user_passes_test(isadministrator,login_url='userauth:forbiddnpage')
```

Now, if the first one returns false the forbidden page is shown. Is there any way i can get all the decorators to get checked before redirecting or giving access. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you want to check both ismanager or isadministrator at one time?

Comment: @seuling yes. Both user types have to be checked.

Comment: Then why don't you make the function including both?

Comment: @seuling but certain views can  only be accessed by one user type

Comment: Then just make function including both and use it for your own needs. you don't have to use same decorator for multiple times. or like @unixia said, you can make your own decorator accept multiple variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test multiple conditions for the same decorator, I suggest you write down a new one which uses `user_passes_test` and variable number of function name args. You can apply the conditions for `ismanager` and `is_administrator` and send the result in lambda to `user_passes_test`.

Motivation for doing this can be [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) decorator which internally uses `user_passes_test` in a similar way.

Also, using the same decorator multiple times like you are doing is making code dirty and is a little redundant, so this would be a better solution.